# 404 Error: unable to serve static content from static_dir

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm unable to serve static content from static_dir (`css`). when I visited the URL http://srvc1.appeng-vj.appspot.com/styles/index.htmll I get 404 Page Not Found error... I had expected the static content, `index.html`, from static_dir `css` should have been served as per app.yaml handlers!

app.yaml as follows:

```
runtime: python
env: flex
runtime_config:
python_version: 3
handlers:
- url: /styles
  static_dir: css
- url: /s1/
  script: home.application
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT m1:application
service: srvc1
```

app root directory structure is as follows (attach screenshot)
[image]

Thanks for any clue what might be wrong here !

Answer (score 1):

Serving static files with `static_dir` is a GAE-Standard capability.  It's able to do that because it is VERY different from GAE-Flexibile (which you appear to be using).

See the GAE-Flexible doc for "[Serving Static Files](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/serving-static-files)": it doesn't say anything at all about using `static_dir`.  For GAE-Flexible, it says your options are "You can serve static content directly from your application, host it on Cloud Storage, or use a third-party content delivery network".